# Format a redux-form field (add a unit)

Tags: reactjs, redux, format, normalization, redux-form

I'm trying to add a unit to a redux field.
The field contains a distance. 
I'd like to set a max value, and to add the unit after that value.

If I type "1000" in the field, the field should show "100cm", and the value persisted to the state should be "100".

I use a normalizer to change the value if the input is too high. That part works.

I use a formatter to add the unit after the value but I think it's not the good way to do it.

When the formatter adds the unit to the value, the value received by the normalizer contains that unit.
The unit is just for display purpose. I don't wanna see it in the normalizer and I don't wanna persist it in the store.
Is there a way to do it.

Here is my code :

```
// Normalizer
const lessThanNormalizer = maxValue => 
    newValue => 
        return newValue<maxValue ? newValue : maxValue;

// Formatter
const unitFormatter = unit => 
    value => 
        value+" "+unit;

// Field component
<Field
    name=      "hardware.distance"
    component= {renderMaterialTextField}
    type=      "text"
    label=     "Distance"
    normalize= {lessThanNormalizer(100)}
    format=    {unitFormatter("cm")}
/>
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Which library does the ```Field``` component belongs to ? (redux is not a component library)

Comment: It's from refux-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
Now everything works really fine.

I hope it can help someone else.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import renderMaterialTextField from "../../../renderMaterialTextField";
import {Field, getFormMeta} from "redux-form";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

// Get a nested object from a string of type w.x[y].z
let resolve = (s,o) => {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    let a = s.split('.');
    for (let i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        let k = a[i];
        if (k in o) { o = o[k]; } else { return; }
    }
    return o;
};

// Normalizer (limit the value)
const minMaxNormalizer = (min,max) => (newValue, previousValue) => {

    if(newValue.trim()==="") newValue=0;
    newValue = parseFloat(newValue);

    if(isNaN(newValue)) {
        newValue=previousValue;
    }else if(newValue>max) {
        return max;
    }else if(newValue<min) {
        return min;
    }
    return newValue;
};

// Formatter (add the unit)
const unitFormatter = (unit,formMeta) => (value, name) => {
    if(value===0) return "";
    let fieldMeta = resolve(name, formMeta); //Get the meta of the field
    if(String(value).trim()==="" || (formMeta[name.split('.')[0]]!==undefined && fieldMeta!==undefined && !!fieldMeta.active)) return value;
    return value+" "+unit;
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Field
                    name="hardware.device1.distance"
                    component={renderMaterialTextField}
                    type="text"
                    label="Distance"
                    normalize={minMaxNormalizer(0,100)}
                    format={unitFormatter("cm", this.props.formMeta)}
                />
                <Field
                    name="hardware.device1.volume"
                    component={renderMaterialTextField}
                    type="text"
                    label="Volume"
                    normalize={minMaxNormalizer(0,50)}
                    format={unitFormatter("L", this.props.formMeta)}
                />
            </>
        )
    }
}

MyComponent = connect(
    state => ({
        formMeta: getFormMeta('myForm')(state)
    })
)(MyComponent);
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it by adding a *parser* on the `parse` prop. ([doc](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-parse-value-name-gt-parsedvalue-code-optional-))

```
// Normalizer
const lessThanNormalizer = maxValue => newValue => newValue < maxValue ? newValue : maxValue;

// Formatter
const unitFormatter = unit => value => value !== undefined ? value + " " + unit : '';

// Parser
const cmParser = value => {
  return value
    .replace(/ /g, "")
    .replace(/c/g, "")
    .replace(/m/g, "")
}

/* ... */

  <Field
    name="field"
    component="input"
    normalize={lessThanNormalizer(100)}
    format={unitFormatter('cm')}
    parse={cmParser}
  />

/* ... */
```

While this works, it's also a bit annoying to change what's written in the input because you need to set the cursor before " cm" to modify the numbers, but this works.

If you want to make it more convenient you may want to set the cursor position programmatically via a ref.

Also, the state in the store doesn't contain the `cm` at the end of the string.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/exifers/pen/povymPE?editors=1111)

Comment: Merci beaucoup Emmanuel! I really appreciate your help! But as you pointed out, the UX isn't the best one, because of the position of the cursor. I just found a solution that seems working very well. Thanks again